# Console Error in Chrome: window.function is not a function

Tags: javascript

In chrome i get the following Error for my JS:

```
Uncaught TypeError: window.picturefill is not a function
```

how can i fix that?

```
function activateVisiblePicturefills() {
    jQuery("span").each(function(i, elm) {
        var $elm = jQuery(elm);

        if (checkvisible($elm)) {
            var content = $elm.html(),
                $pic = jQuery("<picture id=" + $elm.attr("id") + ">" + content + "</picture>").addClass($elm.attr("class")),
                pic = $pic[0];

            $elm.after($pic);  // insert the picture
            $elm.remove();     // remove the span

            window.picturefill({ elements: [ pic ] });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: why would `picturefill` be a function?

Comment: its declared above this function with:  function picturefill( options ) { do omething}. The whole script is very long, i think its becusee of that the function is inside the loop? example http://codepen.io/Chmood/pen/CHlGD/#anon-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have included the picturefill.js script, it's in the global namespace

instead of calling

```
window.picturefill()
```

just call

```
picturefill();
```

Generally speaking, the global namespace is the window object, when called as standard in a browser, but there are exceptions to this.

Comment: hi ben, thank you but then i get: Uncaught ReferenceError: picturefill is not defined

Comment: are you sure you have included the picturefill.js file somewhere in the page?

Comment: yes its all in one file. Got it from here: http://codepen.io/Chmood/pen/CHlGD/#anon-login